# Cannot access website externally, while being able to access it internally

Tags: networking, apache-httpd

The situation is as follows. An Apache-based site is accessible *internally* (from within its server) via `curl`, but not accessible *externally* (nothing, with an exception of `ping`, works: I have tried `curl` as well as browser access) - it **times out**. I have tried to determine the root of the problem, using `netcat`, `netstat`, `traceroute` and `iptables` (as recommended on [this page](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch04_:_Simple_Network_Troubleshooting#Testing_Web_sites_with_the_curl_and_wget_Utilities)), but to no avail.

Here is the `iptables` configuration (note that my active network interface is `eth1`):

```
iptables -L -nv
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 108K packets, 18M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 4575  394K fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
11433 3923K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 5262  481K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    3   156 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:389
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  venet0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  venet0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  venet0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  venet0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:830:831
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1170
    3   180 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  venet0 *       10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  venet0 eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:830:831
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  venet0 eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  venet0 eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  venet0 eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 15571 packets, 4718K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 4575  394K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 2):

First try to disable iptables on the server and try to access the page ,

```
    #service iptables stop
```

For debian:

```
    #iptables -F
```

This will flush all the rules

Also specify the port number with ip if it is not default 80. Also try to set selinux in permissive mode.

```
   #setenforce 0
```

You also need to do port forwarding if the web page serving server is inside virtualbox.

and i suppose by external you mean the local LAN.

Also

Search for LISTEN directive in the apache config files (httpd.conf, apache2.conf, listen.conf,...) and if you see localhost, or 127.0.0.1, then you need to overwrite with your server ip.

```
  listen 192.168.1.15:80
```

I f you want to enable selinux after you discovered that it is an selinux problem then you should allow httpd in selinux ,

```
      # setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

if you discovered that it is an iptables problem then and you want to enable ip tables and keep accessing the page , then allow port 80 in the firewall.

To allow http and https in debian iptables , see this link:

https://github.com/iahmad-khan/system-admin/blob/master/iptables-debian

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1). However, there are some discrepancies between your assumptions and my case, as follows. 1) The site is hosted on a Debian machine, so `service iptables stop` doesn't work; 2) I'm not using SELinux; 3) I'm not using VirtualBox either (it is just an Apache on Debian on a physical PC) - "internal" meant trying to access from the same PC; "external" meant trying to access from Internet; 4) I don't see any `listen` directives in conjunction with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`; though `ports.conf` contains: `NameVirtualHost *:80` and `Listen 80`.

Comment: I have just added my `iptables` configuration - please take a look.

Comment: You need to disable iptables , (i updated the command in my answer ), so that we can know whether the problem is caused by iptables or not , later on if you want iptables then we can insert a rule to allow port 80

Comment: Thank you! I will give your advice a try and report the results.